# Is it possible to load pre-trained lda model into gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, topic-modeling

I've trained an lda model using GuidedLDA (https://guidedlda.readthedocs.io/). Is it possible to transfer this lda model into the gensim framework to continue working with it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a late answer but I am writing it hoping this may help someone later. Yes, you can load a pre-trained model in gensim.

```
lda = LdaModel.load(file_name)
```

You can [check this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#:%7E:text=Optimized%20Latent%20Dirichlet%20Allocation%20(LDA,machines)%2C%20see%20also%20gensim.&text=This%20module%20allows%20both%20LDA,distribution%20on%20new%2C%20unseen%20documents.) for more details.